# How to find available commands in SDF's unvalidated default shell?

Tags: shell, ssh, bsd

[SDF Public Access UNIX System](http://sdf.org/) offers free *BSD* **nix* accounts.  Once logged in via `ssh` to my unvalidated account, (running *SDF's* default shell), there seems to be no obvious command or series of commands to show a *complete* list of currently available and authorized commands.  So far I've tried:

1. `apropos` -- exists in */usr/bin*, but returns:

> not found - try 'help' for commands

2. `help` and `unix`, two *SDF* scripts that show *some* available commands, (but not all), and *some* **un**available or [almost entirely crippled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crippleware) commands (e.g. `chsh` which helpfully offers to change the shell to `bash` *et al*, but unhelpfully refuses to for unvalidated accounts).
3. `echo $PATH` mysteriously outputs `echo $PATH`.
4. Reading *SDF's FAQ*, the text of which presupposes a validated account.
5. `ls -l /usr/bin` shows `ls -l ~` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/\/* }
```

Will print all commands than can be accessed in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Late comment:  Doesn't seem to work, it returns `psh: printf '%sn' ${PATH//://* }: not found - try 'help' for commands'; a further test of just `printf` returns `psh: printf: not found - try 'help' for commands`.